# Ajax Datatables testing with rspec and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rspec, datatables, capybara-webkit

I'm trying to create tests for my app, but I can't make my tests for pages with datatables to work. I'm loading the records to the table with ajax. If I go to the browser everything works fine but none of the tests pass.

Heres my code.

**index.html.slim**

```
table.table.table-striped.table-bordered.table-hover.table-checkable.order-column#dtable data-source="#{ admin_analysts_path(format: :json)}"
  thead
    tr
      th Nome
      th email
  tbody
```

**analysts_controller**
def index
    add_breadcrumb "Todos Analistas"

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render json: AnalystsDatatable.new(view_context)}
end
```

end

**analysts_datatable.rb**

```
class AnalystsDatatable
  delegate :params, :h, :link_to, :number_to_currency, to: :@view

  def initialize(view)
    @view = view
  end

  def as_json(options = {})
    {
      draw: params[:draw].to_i,
      recordsTotal: Analyst.count,
      recordsFiltered: analysts.total_entries,
      data: data
    }
  end

private

  def data
    analysts.map do |analyst|
      [
        link_to(analyst.name, [:admin,analyst]),
        (analyst.email)
      ]
    end
  end

  def analysts
    @analysts ||= fetch_analysts
  end

  def fetch_analysts
    analysts = Analyst.order("#{sort_column} #{sort_direction}")
    analysts = analysts.page(page)
    if params[:length]
      analysts = analysts.per_page(params[:length])
    end
    if params[:search][:value].present?
      analysts = analysts.where("name like :search or email like :search", search: "%#{params[:search][:value]}%")
    end
    analysts
  end

  def page
    params[:start].to_i == 0 ? 1 : ((params[:start].to_i)/params[:length].to_i) +1
  end

  def sort_column
    columns = %w[name email]
    columns[params[:order]['0'][:column].to_i]

  end

  def sort_direction
    params[:order]['0'][:dir] == "desc" ? "desc" : "asc"
  end
end
```

And my test configuration for javascript
**spec_helper.rb**

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit
```

and finally my test

```
scenario 'check all analysts', :js => true  do

    login_as administrator, scope: :administrator

    analyst1
    visit admin_analysts_path

    expect(page).to have_content("#{analyst.name}")
    expect(page).to have_content("#{analyst1.name}")
  end
```

I saw one answer that sugested to change the capybara server because the get uri was to large, I changed to puma but it didn't work. Also tried to use find method that is said to wait till the element is loaded.

Any suggestion is valid, thanks.

Comment: Look in your `test.log` and see if the requests actually being made to the app are what you expect

Comment: Where are you tests failing? I maintain two different rails/datatables apps, and they both fail on the `expect(page).to have_content("#{analyst.name}")`. 

My next thing to try is [wait_for_ajax](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/automatically-wait-for-ajax-with-capybara). I tried it in one without much success, but haven't tried it in the other yet.

Comment: @Matheus Mendes have you been able to fix this? I have exact same problem.

Comment: @jedi sorry, I don't remember what I did, and I don't have access to that codebase anymore.